# What happens if everything is magnetic?

Tags: science-based, earth

What would happen if everything in the Earth suddenly gained the magnetism of a standard fridge magnet? (Ignoring the fact that this would change atomic structures.) Things that were already magnetic maintain normal magnetism in this scenario. Things that are diamagnetic retain diamagneticism.

This probably ends badly. I don't know.

Comment: I am pretty sure it would just "instantly" collapse into a black hole. Electromagnetism is uhm... 10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 times stronger than gravity. So chances are, the instance this switch was made, every object held together under gravity would collapse into a black hole.

Comment: @ErikHall maybe I should limit it to Earth...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an off-topic [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609), meaning it's too broad, open-ended, opinion-based, and all answers would be equally valid (all of which are prohibited in the [help/dont-ask]).

Comment: @JBH I don't see how it is a high concept question or an opinion based one, but it may be too open ended. I will edit it to add background and define the problem further.

Comment: @JBH it's only opinion-based insofar as "everything" getting the same magnetism "as a fridge magnet" is a bit vague in terms of exact strength.  All it means is that the quantitative timeframes are unclear for every life form to die (somewhere between nanoseconds and milliseconds?) and for the entire planetary mass to form a single, molten, uniformly magnetically aligned body (days?).  The qualitative outcome is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 that's a lot of unclear things to claim the quesiton isn't opinion-based. If we choose to simplify it by modeling the Earth as a homogeneous ball of ferrite, have we really answered the OP's question? How would an individual react if they were suddenly a magnetic dipole? More to the point... what frame of reference do you intend to use to explain what will happen? Further, questions of the form, "I change one thing... what happens next?" have always been off-topic on the site.

Comment: @Zautech Please read the linked Meta post carefully. Questions of the form "I change one thing... what happens next?" have always been off-topic here. I merely explained what about them makes them off-topic.

Comment: @JBH if the experience was remotely survivable for anyone I would agree.  If the question was "What would happen to life on Earth if the moon was suddenly turned transformed into a giant night light?" then the possible outcomes are opinion-based and very complex.  This is more along the lines of "What would happen to life on Earth if a supernova occurred within a couple of light years?" - the outcome that "there would be no life, everything would be dead" is a certainty that can be briefly stated.

Comment: Which does raise the point - @Zautech if you change the question such that the magnetic level is low enough that it is survivable, then it is a high-concept, opinion-based question that I would also vote to close.  (You also shouldn't change questions to invalidate answers that have already been provided.)

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 I fixed it. If everyone dies... oh well.

Comment: actually everything is magnetic just that the effect is cancelled out, so long you don't change the fundamental constants or Maxwell's eqs you should be fine i guess ;D

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 If that could be proven to the expectations of the [tag:hard-science] tag, then I would remove my vote. Care to take a crack at it? 'Cause I don't think it's as cut-and-dried as you're assuming.

Comment: 1) What if X happens? is not a good question here. See [help]. 2) you can't edit a question in ways which invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

*Answer to original question:* I like to think that I have decent physics knowledge. With that in mind, I have no idea how to even try and model such a universe on any level. I would find it very hard to justify the existence of complex *matter*, let alone complex life. Atoms would be really, really weird, and I doubt anything interesting would happen past the first four hundred million years of the Universe's existence.

If you just flipped the magnetism switch from "some" to "all", pretty quickly the mass-energy of the unbelievably-enormous electromagnetic field produced by every atom in the universe combined would tear spacetime apart and collapse everything into black holes and/or cause the Big Rip.

Please don't do that.

*Answer to updated question:* Well, it would be interesting. I think most biological life would die off pretty quickly, given that their blood would start not flowing in the direction it's supposed to due to the magnetic field. Beyond that, it might be really cool: big stone islands floating in the sky due to magnetic repulsion between the island's stone and the ground? Sounds interesting.

But everyone would be way too dead to witness it, so...

Comment: I'll try, thanks.

Comment: I changed it to just Earth. I think your answer still applies, just limited to Earth. (Earth's core creates a magnetic field, so perhaps it is unaffected)

Comment: It might not destroy the universe but it would still kill everyone, I think. See updated answer! :)